# Application does not start after introducing Swagger dependencies in project

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

Jersey 1.19
Swagger 1.5.10
Yammer 2.1.5

Application does not start after introducing Swagger dependencies in project.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have these dependencies as well.

```
Jersey 1.19
Swagger 1.5.10
Yammer 2.1.5
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>   
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>webappMetricsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.yammer.metrics.web.DefaultWebappMetricsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>       
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>My REST API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.samples.springannotations.resources.jerseymanaged;com.yammer.metrics.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>se.abcd.api.service.registry.CacheControlFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter;se.abcd.api.filters.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter;se.abcd.api.filters.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Metrics</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.yammer.metrics.reporting.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>My REST API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Metrics</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/system/metrics/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/docs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webappMetricsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

Error
**

```
dec 15, 2016 08:35:15 FM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.sun.jersey.samples.springannotations.resources.jerseymanaged
  com.yammer.metrics.jersey
```

**

```
    Dec 15, 2016 8:35:20 FM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
    INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
      com.sun.jersey.samples.springannotations.resources.jerseymanaged
      com.yammer.metrics.jersey
    [WARNING] failed My REST API: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
    [WARNING] failed ContextHandlerCollection@2779acb2: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
    [WARNING] failed HandlerCollection@2af781f3: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
    [ERROR] Error starting handlers
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:94)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
```

Comment: This question may be related to yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836551/nosuchmethoderror-com-sun-jersey-core-reflection-reflectionhelper-getosgiregist

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30103510/2893693

Comment: @Berger. Thank you,, This has helped